# Vim file name completion relative to current file

Tags: vim, path

In [Vim](/tags/vim/info), when I am in insert mode, and I want to use file-name completion, I want the search path to be relative to the current file, not the current working directory.  For instance, if in insert mode I type the following:

> `./`[<kbd>^X</kbd><kbd>^F</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#compl-filename)

The completion menu is showing me files in the [`:pwd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:pwd), but I would rather see the files in [`%:p:h`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#filename-modifiers) listed.

Is there an option that I can set to fix this, and if not what do you suggest as a workaround?

Answer (score 14):

If you

```
:set autochdir
```

you'll get the behavior you desire. However, if you need to keep the working directory (e.g. to easily open other project files), you'd have to save / restore the CWD with autocmds:

```
:autocmd InsertEnter * let save_cwd = getcwd() | set autochdir
:autocmd InsertLeave * set noautochdir | execute 'cd' fnameescape(save_cwd)
```

Comment: Thank you!  `autochdir` was great for `C-X`, `C-F`, but annoying when I'm 4 levels deep in a project and I want to `:tabe`

Answer (score 5):

@[Ingo Karkat](https://superuser.com/users/117820/ingo-karkat)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/604180/3304) is nice, but I am a little hesitant to put that in [my vimrc](https://github.com/kaleb/vim-files), because even the [help page for `'autochdir'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'autochdir') gives a note that it's useage will break some plugins.

I have come up with my own solution which may be very niche to my use-cases:

> [inoremap](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:inoremap) ./[<C-X><C-F>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#compl-filename) [<C-O>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-O)[:lcd](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:lcd) [%:p:h](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#filename-modifiers)[<CR>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#keycodes)[<C-X><C-F>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#compl-filename)

I plan on extracting it out into a function and setting a variable for the pwd before the lcs command is issued and then resetting it at some point in time.  It would be nice if there was a menu autocmd.

I may or may not use this, but I thought I would throw out another solution.

Comment: It's implied in your answer but please note that this has the side effect of changing the current working directory for the current window.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
" [relative autocomplete]
" ==============================================================================
" Vim's file autocomplete (C-X C-F) works only in an absolute path (using the
" current working directory) as base. But in most languages, you want to use
" relative imports, and file autocomplete doesn't work there. For that, I use
" <C-X><C-X><C-F>:

function! s:EnableRelativeAutocomplete() abort
  let b:relative_autocomplete_cleanup_pending = 1
  lcd %:p:h
endfunction

function! s:DisableRelativeAutocomplete() abort
  if exists('b:relative_autocomplete_cleanup_pending') && b:relative_autocomplete_cleanup_pending
    lcd -
    let b:relative_autocomplete_cleanup_pending = 0
  endif
endfunction

inoremap <C-x><C-x><C-f> <C-o>:call <SID>EnableRelativeAutocomplete()<CR><C-x><C-f>

augroup relative_file_autocomplete
  autocmd!
  autocmd InsertLeave * call s:DisableRelativeAutocomplete()
augroup END
```

It will change the working directory to the current file's when using `<C-x><C-x><C-f>` and back to the previous directory when leaving insert mode, if needed.